# Prove the equation and show the solution set is a circle.

Tags: complex-analysis

[image]

I'm stuck on this. Any suggestions on how to start?

Comment: Hint: Let $z=x+iy$ and $a=a_1+ia_2$, where $a_i \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Write first $a=A\epsilon$, where $A\ge 0$ and $\epsilon$ has modulus $1$. Now, using $z/\epsilon$ instead of $z$ we get a similar equation, with $a$ replaced be the real non-negative number $A$. (The transformation $z\to z/\epsilon$ sends circles in circles.) So we may and do assume $a=A$ is real, non-negative. Next, write $$0=|z|^2 + \frac A2(z+\bar z) + b=\left(z\bar z + \frac A2(z+\bar z) +\frac{A^2}4\right) -\frac{A^2}4+ b\ .$$ The parenthesis can be factored. How?